# Custom annotation to modify string data type not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a custom java annotation that can act on String data types in data classes and modify their values when they are set. So for instance lets say I have

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Modify
    private String userName;
}
```

The expectation is that when userName is set I want the userName's value to be modified as userName+"someValue"

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Modify {
   String value() default "someValue";
}
```

When I create a new User object and set the userName value using a setter, its not getting modified.

Comment: yeah...annotations are not at the AI level yet, they don't magically do what you want them to. If you want this annotation to do something you will need to write the code that searches for this annotation and sets the corresponding value. In SpringBoot there is a somewhat similar annotation present that you might like - `@Value("someValue")` - see more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation). Using Spring [SpEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) you can do pretty cool things with it.

Comment: What code have you written to find the annotation, cause the setter to be intercepted, and modify the value? Please add that to your question.

Comment: I just learned that there needs to be code that checks for the annotation and performs the edit. I initially incorrectly assumed that the String value() default "someValue"; 
adds the value to the field if Target is set toElementType.FIELD

Extracting the fields of the class and iterating through them to check if the field has the annotation and then modifying it made it work.